# DataGridView don't go into Edit Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, edit

I fill DataGridView this way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MARKETConnectionString))
{
     conn.Open();

     String SQL = @"select INN, Idx, Adr, 'P' as Src from AdrP where Idx is null 
                    union all
                    select INN, Idx, Adr, 'K' as Src  from AdrK where Idx is null";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
     var RD = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     if (RD.HasRows) dt.Load(RD);
     dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
}
```

But DataGridView don't go into edit mode by double click. If I remove `'Union All'` in SQL query then double click works properly (switches the DataGridView in edit mode). But I need select from two tables with Union.

I try to call `dataGridView2.BeginEdit(true)` in DataGridView DoubleClick event. But it does not help.

What is the right way to edit DataGridView with Data Source selected from two tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a DataReader in this case.  Use an Adapter instead:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, conn)) {
  adp.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine. But why DataReader don't work properly in this case?

Comment: @gouph The reader knows the "union" isn't an editable table, so it marks it as read-only internally (or something like that).  The Adapter fill method doesn't make that assumption.  Of course, to save the data, you have to provide the custom mechanism yourself, since the DataTable doesn't know where the data came from.